# Asyncronus function return

Tags: javascript, titanium

I'm working at an application in Titanium Studio. I have an MVC infrastructure implemented, and in a controller I want to get some data from the Cloud and only after that to call the view. The code is similar to this.

```
 Default : function() {
    Cloud.Objects.query({
        classname : 'Customer',
    }, function(e) {
            if (e.success) {
                Ti.API.info('aci ' + e.Customer);
                favorites = e.Customer;
                return this.view("Default", favorites);
            } else {
                alert('Error:\\n' + ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
            }
        });
    },
}
```

The thing is, that the first function has to return "this.view("Default", favorites);", not the callback from the query. Also, the query function is asyncronus and I have to wait for the data, and only then call the view.

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an even handler for some custom event like `receiveCustomer`.

When customer retrieved, fire the event `receiveCustomer` and set customer as event data or initialize some variable outside the callback with retrieved data (but in this case before event triggering). In event hander `onReceiveCustomer` get the customer from the event data or from that variable and render the view.

Comment: I wanted to do it like this, but again, the main function has to return this.view(...). If I create an eventListener, I have the same problem, because the event listener also receives a function as a callback, and if I put my return there, that function will return the view, not the main function